# Regex pattern for matching single quoted words in a string and ignore the escaped single quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$input = "City.name = 'New York'";
$literal_pattern = '/\'.[^\']*\'/';
preg_match($literal_pattern, $input, $token);
echo $token[0]; // prints 'New York'
```

My regex needs to grab literals with escaped single quotes like:

```
$input = "City.name = 'New \' York'";
$literal_pattern = ???????????;
preg_match($literal_pattern, $input, $token);
echo $token[0]; // should prints 'New \' York'
```

What wil be the reges for $literal_pattern ?

Comment: I think your two inputs are the same. Because you use `"`, all backslashes will be evaluated on string-creation, so that the string does not actually contain the character `\ `. If you want a literal backslash you would need two backslashes `\\ ` (ignore the trailing space in both cases, I can't seem to code-format a single backslash)

Comment: @m.buettner Afair, `\'` is actually a single quote in `'...'` string literal too. I'm not sure about nowdocs, though; will check it now. )

Comment: @raina77ow but then it would be more obvious because the other `'` would need the backslash, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without this condition, simple...

```
/('[^']*')/
```

...would suffice, of course: match all sequences of "single quote, followed by any number of non-single-quote symbols, followed by a single quote again".

But as we need to be ready for two *things* here - both "normal" and "escaped" ones. So we should add some spice to our pattern:

```
/('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*')/
```

It might look odd (and it is), but it's actually pretty simple too: match sequences of...

- single quote symbol...
- ...followed by zero or more "normal" characters (not `'` or `\`),
- ...followed by a subexpression of ("escaped" symbol, then zero or more "normal" ones), repeated 0 or more times...
- followed by a single quote symbol.

Example:

```
$input   = "City.name = 'New \\' York (And Some Backslash Fun)\\\\'\\'"; 
# ...as \' in any string literal will be parsed as a _single_ quote

$pattern = "/('[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*')/";
# ... a choice: escape either slashes or single quotes; I choose the former

preg_match($pattern, $input, $token);
echo $token[0]; // 'New \' York (And Some Backslash Fun)\\'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the regex you look for: `/\'(\\.|[^\'\\])*\'/`

In PHP, this would look like `$literal_pattern = '/(\'(?:\\.|[^\'\\])*\')/';`

Comment: The capturing isn't quite right here: it should be `/\'((?:\\.|[^\'\\])*)\'/`

Comment: sorry, forgot about capturing groups

Comment: when I run the code: with $literal_pattern = '/(\'(?:\\.|[^\'\\])*\')/'; I get: PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 17 in test.php on line 5

Comment: That's because you used `\]`, an escaped brace instead of `\\]`, an escaped backslash followed by a brace.  Happy regexing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is automatically greedy, so it will catch as much data as it can using the literal. So, if you recognize "everything between `'`s", it will catch anything between the first and last `'`.

Thus, you can safely do this:

```
$literal_pattern = "#('.*')#";
```

*Example: http://ideone.com/gI5bXs*

*NB: As [@m.buettner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633117/m-buettner) pointed out, this method will only work if there is one `'`-encased string in your input.*

Comment: Will cause problems if `$input` suddenly contains multiple strings.

Comment: @m.buettner Indeed it will; the OP didn't say whether or not multiple strings would be an issue in the string. If they're not, this will work.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm not saying your solution is wrong or invalid or anything, I just think that caveats like this should be pointed out. ;) But you already did that now, so +1.

Comment: You'd also then have to remove the `\'` and replace with `'`, I guess.

Comment: @nickf Yes, if he wanted to. His post does say "should prints 'New \' York'", so I assume he wants to keep the slash.

Comment: @Eric ah yes, I just noticed that afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use negative lookbehind matching. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

> `(?<!a)b` matches a "b" that is not preceded by an "a", using negative lookbehind

The only thing is that I'm pretty sure that PHP regexes don't support that. If they were supported, the regex would look something like this:

```
/(?<!\\)'(.*?)(?<!\\)'/
```

My advice would be to use a simple parser. Here's something I just made up off the top of my head (obviously in pseudocode): no guarantees its logic will work for your purposes, but it's actually not too hard to build yourself.

```
let inString = false
let escaping = false
let match = ''    
for each letter in string
    if letter == "\\" and not escaping
        escaping = true
    else
        if letter == "'" and not escaping
            inString = not inString
        else if inString
            match += letter
        escaping = false
return match
```